# Counting and Probability - Card Game

Tags: combinatorics

There are three cards in front of you, all face down. Each card has a real number written on it. You know that all three numbers are different, but you do not know what the numbers are.

You are allowed to choose a card and turn it over. At this point, you can either keep the card, or discard the card, and turn over a second card. Once you discard a card, you cannot return to it.

You have same option with the second card: You can either keep the second card, or discard it, and turn over the third card. If you discard the second card, your only option left is to turn over the third card and keep it.

At the end, if you have the card with the highest number on it, then you win a valuable prize. Otherwise, you leave empty-handed. If you follow the optimal strategy, then what is the probability that you win the prize?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: This question is lacking information. Is every real number equally likely to be written on a card? Are you applying measure theory? Can numbers be arbitrarily large, yet still fit on a card? Most likely, there is no "optimal strategy". No matter how large of a number you find, there is equal probability that the next card is higher or lower.  You can say that there is a 50% chance that a card is greater than 0 and a 50% chance that a card is less than zero. But, what about greater than or less than 1? That also seems to be 50/50.

Comment: As a crude strategy:  I'd pass on the first card and take the second if it exceed the first, otherwise take the third.

Comment: @almagest  Oh, I think you can do better. As in the [Secretary Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), you can use the first card as a guide to evaluate the second.

Comment: Numberphile has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWib5olGbQ0) that is somewhat related to this question.

Comment: @lulu yes. Your strategy gives you a 1/2 chance of winning. Only order matters. So call cards 1,2,3. If they are picked in the order 132,213,231 then your strategy wins.

Comment: @almagest  Exactly.  I have just posted exactly that below.

Comment: **Please do not post solutions to this problem!** This is a homework problem, and the original poster is simply trying to cheat. I know, because I am in the same class, and I have the same homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the problems connected with probability distributions on the reals, I would simply say that you have three distinct values on the cards and that the player has no idea how they were selected.  Or, if you prefer, imagine that the numbers themselves are not seen by the player, but that someone outside the game knows them and will tell you which of two observed cards is the greater.

Consider this strategy:  Pass on the first, and take the second if it exceeds the first, otherwise take the third.

Let's analyze that.

We have three values $A>B>C$ in some order.  I assume that each order is equally likely.  My strategy loses if $A$ is first, and it loses in the order $(C,B,A)$.  Thus it loses in three of the six possible cases, making the probability of success $\frac 12$.

This is clearly optimal.  There's no way to evaluate the number on the first card, so stopping there wins with probability $\frac 13$.  Similarly, if you wait until the third card, you have success probability $\frac 13$.  Of course the problem changes if you have some objective standard to tell you if a number is "big".